# test fails because of TestMethod do not support getContent call

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, deployment, failing-tests

My below test fails because of Run Failures:
TestRangehoodObjectionSheet.RangehoodObjectionSheetTest Methods defined as TestMethod do not support getContent call. I added the Blob thinking it might resolve but it doesn't work. What could be the problem here? Have I used the Blob correctly?

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestRangehoodObjectionSheet {
     static testMethod void RangehoodObjectionSheetTest() {
            String Build                = NBATRecords.getIdFromDeveloperName('Plan_Reviews__c','Building_Plan_Review');
            Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test1' ,Type = 'Lead Acct',BillingState = 'CA',Industry = 'Business Services');
            insert a;

            Establishment_Record__c er = new Establishment_Record__c(Account__c=a.Id ,Project_Name__c = 'TestPreet',PremiseStreet__c='Manhattan ave',PremiseBorough__c='Manhattan',PremiseState__c='NY',PremisePostalCode__c='11102',Referral_Source__c='311',Data_Source__c='CAMIS',Phase__c='Initiate',Business_Status__c='Open' );
            insert er;

            Application__c ap = new Application__c(Establishment_Record__c=er.Id,Job_Number__c='222222222');
            insert ap;

            Plan_Reviews__c pr = new Plan_Reviews__c(Application__c =ap.Id ,DOB_Job_Number__c='222222222',RecordTypeId =Build,Objections__c='Pipe size not indicated');
            insert pr;
            PageReference pageRef = Page.RangehoodObjectionSheet;

            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 

            Blob content = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : pageRef.getContent();

            Plan_Reviews__c              p   = new Plan_Reviews__c(id=pr.Id);



            ApexPages.StandardController sc  = new ApexPages.standardController(p);
            System.assertNotEquals(sc,null);
            RangehoodObjectionExtention    ext = new RangehoodObjectionExtention(sc);

            ext.Savecopy();

     }
}
```

Actual class for the test:

```
public with sharing class RangehoodObjectionExtention {
private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
private final Id                           planreviewID;
public String imageURL{get;set;}
public List<String> objlist {get;set;} 
public string currentdate {get; set;}
   public RangehoodObjectionExtention (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        controller   = stdController;
        planreviewID = (Id)controller.getRecord().get('Id');
        Date dt = Date.today();
        currentdate = dt.format();
        list<Plan_Reviews__c> prlist = [select FDNY_Objections__c from Plan_Reviews__c where id = :planreviewID limit 1];
        string obj;
        for(Plan_Reviews__c pr: prlist){
           obj = pr.FDNY_Objections__c;    
        }
        if(obj!=null){
           list<string> objections = obj.split(';'); 
           integer i =1;
           objlist = new list<string>();
           for(string o : objections){
              objlist.add(i++ +'. '+o);
           }
        }
        imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
        List< document > documentList=[select name from document where Name='RangehoodObjectionLogo'];
        if(documentList.size()>0)
        {
           imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
        }   
   }     

   public PageReference Savecopy(){
      PageReference p = Page.RangehoodObjectionSheet;
      blob b = ApexPages.currentPage().getContentAsPDF ();
      Attachment a = new Attachment();
      a.body = b;
      a.name = 'Rangehood Objection sheet Issued '+currentdate+'.pdf';
      a.parentid = planreviewID;

      insert a;

      PageReference pref = new PageReference('/'+planreviewID);
      return pref;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was an update made in winter 16 which states that getcontent is also considered as a webservice Callout .So you may consider writing your test class using mock callouts .Never use get content inside test class

```
 @isTest
 public with sharing class TestRangehoodObjectionSheet {

    static testMethod void RangehoodObjectionSheetTest() {
        String build = NBATRecords.getIdFromDeveloperName('Plan_Reviews__c','Building_Plan_Review');
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test1' ,Type = 'Lead Acct',BillingState = 'CA',Industry = 'Business Services');
        insert a;

        Establishment_Record__c er = new Establishment_Record__c(Account__c=a.Id ,Project_Name__c = 'TestPreet',PremiseStreet__c='Manhattan ave',PremiseBorough__c='Manhattan',PremiseState__c='NY',PremisePostalCode__c='11102',Referral_Source__c='311',Data_Source__c='CAMIS',Phase__c='Initiate',Business_Status__c='Open' );
        insert er;

        Application__c ap = new Application__c(Establishment_Record__c=er.Id,Job_Number__c='222222222');
        insert ap;

        Plan_Reviews__c pr = new Plan_Reviews__c(Application__c =ap.Id ,DOB_Job_Number__c='222222222',RecordTypeId =Build,Objections__c='Pipe size not indicated');
        insert pr;
        PageReference pageRef = Page.RangehoodObjectionSheet;

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 

        Blob content == Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');//Just use blob.value of .In your actual code you can add istestRunning

        Plan_Reviews__c p = new Plan_Reviews__c(id=pr.Id);
        
        ApexPages.StandardController sc  = new ApexPages.standardController(p);
        System.assertNotEquals(sc,null);
        RangehoodObjectionExtention    ext = new RangehoodObjectionExtention(sc);

        ext.Savecopy();

     }
 }
```

Skip the Blob content in test class

```
public PageReference Savecopy(){

    PageReference p = Page.RangehoodObjectionSheet;
    blob b;
    if(!test.isRunningTest()){
      b = ApexPages.currentPage().getContentAsPDF ();
    }else{
      b = blob.valueof('TEST');
    }
    Attachment a = new Attachment();
    a.body = b;
    a.name = 'Rangehood Objection sheet Issued '+currentdate+'.pdf';
    a.parentid = planreviewID;

    insert a;

    PageReference pref = new PageReference('/'+planreviewID);
    return pref;
}
```