# Help with writing test class for SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, singleemailmessage

I am struggle with writing test class for SingleEmailMessage. I have only 33% of coverage, and only 18/53 lines are coveraged. I used the For loop in my EmailClass, and everything after for (Case cs : cases) is not coveraged.

Here is my class:

```
  public class EmailClass
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail() {

        
 //Contact and Case lists
    List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
    
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    cases = [Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c, Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center__c, 
             Status, ContactId, Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c, Actual_Follow_up_Date__c From Case 
             Where ContactEmail!=null AND subject='Periodic Service' AND account.company_code__c='US45' AND Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND Status='Ready for Email' AND Letter_Sent__c = false AND Reminder_Sent__c = false AND ContactId IN : contacts];
   
    List<Case> cases2 = new List<Case>();    
    cases2 = [Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c, Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center__c, 
             Status, ContactId, Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c, Actual_Follow_up_Date__c From Case 
             Where ContactEmail!=null AND Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c = 0 AND subject='Periodic Service' AND account.company_code__c='US45' AND Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND Status='Waiting for Customer' AND Letter_Sent__c = true AND Reminder_Sent__c = false AND ContactId IN : contacts];
    
        
        
        
 //ORG Wide Email Addresses lists   
        
    OrgWideEmailAddress AST = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
                AST = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Austin']; 
        
    OrgWideEmailAddress ATL = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
                ATL = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Atlanta'];
        

        
        
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (Case cs : cases)
    {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
    List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
    toAddress.add(cs.ContactEmail);
    email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
    
    email.setWhatId(cs.Id);
    email.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
    email.setTemplateId('00X7Z0000027tioUAA');
    
    email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
    //email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.id);
    //List<String> ccAddress = new List<String>();
    //email.setCcAddresses(ccAddress);
    //email.setSaveAsActivity(true); 
    
    
    //First email reminder
    //Letter_Sent_Date__c and Follow_up_Date__c updated in Cases Processes for first reminder
    
    if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='AST' && cs.status=='Ready for Email' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == false && cs.Reminder_Sent__c == false)
    {
        cs.status = 'Waiting for Customer';
        cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(AST.id);
    }
    
    if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='ATL' && cs.status=='Ready for Email' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == false && cs.Reminder_Sent__c == false)
    {
        cs.status = 'Waiting for Customer';
        cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ATL.id);
    } 
        
        else
    {
        system.debug('no mail was sent');
    }
    
    emails.add(email);}
   
    
   //Second email reminder
   
    for (Case cs2 : cases2)
{
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email2 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
    List<String> toAddress2 = new List<String>();
    toAddress2.add(cs2.ContactEmail);
    email2.setToAddresses(toAddress2);
    
    email2.setWhatId(cs2.Id);
    email2.setTargetObjectId(cs2.ContactId);
    email2.setTemplateId('00X7Z0000027tioUAA');
    
    email2.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
    cs2.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
   
    if (cs2.Responsibility_Center__c =='AST' && cs2.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs2.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs2.Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c == 0)
    {     
        cs2.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        email2.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(AST.id);
    }
    
    if (cs2.Responsibility_Center__c =='ATL' && cs2.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs2.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs2.Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c == 0)
    {
        cs2.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        email2.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ATL.id);
    }
    
    else
    {
        system.debug('no mail was sent');
    }
    
    emails.add(email2);
    }
   else
    {
        system.debug('no mail was sent');
    }
    
 
    emails.add(email2);
} 

    Messaging.sendEmail(emails); 
    update cases;
    update cases2;    
  } 
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class EmailClassTest {
   @isTest
    public static void sendEmail(){
            
        //Insert Profile
      Profile cus = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='DGS - Customer Service'];   
        
        
        //Insert User
      User us = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = cus.Id, CompanyName = 'E3',
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com'); 
        
        
        //Insert Account
      Account acct = new Account(Name='TestClassAccount', Customer_Segment__c = 'Hospitals', Calibration_Intervals__c = 'Half year');
      insert acct;
        
        
        //Insert Contact
      Contact con = new Contact(LastName='JasonSendEmail', email='sendemail@toatlanta.com', AccountId=acct.Id);
      insert con;
        
        
        //Insert Responsibility Center
      Responsibility_Center__c rc = new Responsibility_Center__c(Name='e3 AST');
        
        
        //Insert Case
       Case cas = new Case(Status = 'Ready for Email', ContactId=con.id, subject='Periodic Service', AccountId = acct.id,
                          Case_Reason__c = 'Business related', Reason = 'General Enquiry', Responsibility_Center_lookup__c=rc.id, Reminder_Sent__c = false, Letter_Sent__c = false,
                          Follow_up_date__c = datetime.newInstance(2022, 10, 15, 12, 30, 0));
       insert cas; 
        //Insert 2nd Case
       Case cas2 = new Case(Follow_up_Date__c = date.today(), Status = 'Waiting for Customer', ContactId=con.id, subject='Periodic Service', AccountId = acct.id,
                          Case_Reason__c = 'Business related', Reason = 'General Enquiry', Responsibility_Center_lookup__c=rc.id, Reminder_Sent__c = false, Letter_Sent__c = true);
       insert cas2; 
         
        
       //Insert Org-wide
       OrgWideEmailAddress[] addresses = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Austin'];      
            
    
       Test.startTest();
       System.assertEquals(0, Limits.getEmailInvocations(), 'No emails should be sent');

       EmailClass.sendEmail();

       System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations(), 'Emails should be sent');
      
       Test.stopTest();
        
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to add:

System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Case WHERE Id = :cas.id AND Letter_Sent__c = true], 'Case should have changed status'); - but then I get the error about wrong asseration.

Comment: I see you have below filter for case query`account.company_code__c='US45' AND Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND Status='Ready for Email' AND Letter_Sent__c = false AND Reminder_Sent__c = false` but for Account record you did not defined company_code__c, Same with Actual_Follow_up_Date__c and other filters

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/123786/how-to-test-messaging-sendemail FYI, this post should resolve your doubt

Comment: The company code on Account is formula field, which is set based on User which is creating the Account. I add the User with CompanyName = 'E3' which is automatically set the company code for User for US45 :)

Comment: Did you check other conditions because it is not entering into for loop which might be records were not satisfying the conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic has a number of bugs. Even if you'd gotten this to production, you would have faced errors in your org. I'm just going to go down the list of your problems from top to bottom.

---

```
List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
```

You cannot just query an unlimited amount of data. The moment you get close to 50,000 Contacts with an email, your code will break. It's also unnecessary, as you'll see later.

---

```
List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
cases = [Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c, Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center__c, 
         Status, ContactId, Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c, Actual_Follow_up_Date__c From Case 
         Where ContactEmail!=null AND subject='Periodic Service' AND account.company_code__c='US45' AND Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND Status='Ready for Email' AND Letter_Sent__c = false AND Reminder_Sent__c = false AND ContactId IN : contacts];
```

You're initializing your variable twice. It's simply not necessary. You can assign the query directly to the variable.

---

You have two very nearly identical queries which collects too much data. Instead of writing conditions in Apex, try to write them in your query; this reduces CPU time, memory usage, and query row usage. Here's an optimized query that finds all the records you want:

```
List<Case> cases = [
    Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c, 
    Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name,
    Status, ContactId, Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c, Actual_Follow_up_Date__c 
    From Case 
    Where ContactEmail!=null AND 
    subject='Periodic Service' AND 
    account.company_code__c='US45' AND 
    Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND 
    Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name IN ('AST','ATL') AND
    (
        (
            Status='Ready for Email' AND 
            Letter_Sent__c = false AND 
            Reminder_Sent__c = false
        ) OR (
            Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c = 0 AND 
            Status='Waiting for Customer' AND 
            Letter_Sent__c = true AND 
            Reminder_Sent__c = false
        )
    ) AND
    ContactId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email != NULL)
];
```

---

Likewise, you can combine your org-wide email addresses:

```
Map<String, Id> orgWideAddresses = new Map<String, Id>();
for(OrgWideEmailAddress orgAddress: [SELECT DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName IN ('Austin','Atlanta')]) {
    orgWideAddresses.put(orgAddress.DisplayName, orgAddress.Id);
}
```

---

```
email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
```

That's unnecessary. Just set the target object Id, and you don't need to build the toAddresses and setting the address that way.

---

Don't hardcode ID values, always prefer to use a query. Your code won't be portable between orgs (e.g. production, sandboxes). I don't know the actual template names, so set the correct values here:

```
Map<String, Id> templateIds = new Map<String, Id>();
for(EmailTemplate template: [SELECT DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName IN ('Template1','Template2')]) {
    templateIds.put(template.DeveloperName, template.Id);
}
```

---

We can also make the field update dynamic:

```
Map<String, sObjectField> fieldToSet = new Map<String, sObjectField> {
    'Ready for Email' => Case.Letter_Sent__c,
    'Waiting for Customer' => Case.Reminder_Sent__c
};
```

...

```
cs.put(fieldToSet.get(cs.Status), true);
```

---

As far as the unit test goes, you named your Responsibility Center "e3 AST", when it should have been "AST" or "ATL." Also, it appears you're using a formula field; this results in full table scans for these centers, which may cause selective query errors as your database grows. Consider using the relationship field directly, which is indexed:

```
Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name IN ('AST','ATL')
```

---

Putting this all together, we end up with:

```
public class EmailClass {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail() {
    //Contact and Case lists
    List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
    
    List<Case> cases = [
        Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c,
        Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name,
        Status, ContactId, Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c, Actual_Follow_up_Date__c 
        From Case 
        Where ContactEmail!=null AND 
        subject='Periodic Service' AND 
        account.company_code__c='US45' AND 
        Actual_Follow_up_Date__c = true AND 
        Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name IN ('AST','ATL') AND
        (
            (
                Status='Ready for Email' AND 
                Letter_Sent__c = false AND 
                Reminder_Sent__c = false
            ) OR (
                Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c = 0 AND 
                Status='Waiting for Customer' AND 
                Letter_Sent__c = true AND 
                Reminder_Sent__c = false
            )
        ) AND
        ContactId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Email != NULL)
    ];
    Map<String, Id> orgWideAddresses = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(OrgWideEmailAddress orgAddress: [SELECT DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE DisplayName IN ('Austin','Atlanta')]) {
        orgWideAddresses.put(orgAddress.DisplayName, orgAddress.Id);
    }
    Map<String, Id> templateIds = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(EmailTemplate template: [SELECT DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName IN ('Template1','Template2')]) {
        templateIds.put(template.DeveloperName, template.Id);
    }
    Map<String, String> cityToAbbrev = new Map<String, String>{
        'ATL' => 'Atlanta',
        'AST' => 'Austin'
    };
    Map<String, Id> statusToTemplateName = new Map<String, Id>{
        'Ready for Email' => templateIds.get('Template1'),
        'Waiting for Customer' => templateIds.get('Template2')
    };
    Map<String, sObjectField> fieldToSet = new Map<String, sObjectField> {
        'Ready for Email' => Case.Letter_Sent__c,
        'Waiting for Customer' => Case.Reminder_Sent__c
    };
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (Case cs : cases) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
        email.setWhatId(cs.Id);
        email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);
        String cityName = cityToAbbrev.get(cs.Responsibility_Center_Lookup__r.Name);
        Id templateId = statusToTemplateName.get(cs.Status);
        Id orgEmailId = orgWideAddresses.get(cityName);
        email.setTemplateId(templateId);
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgEmailId);
        emails.add(email);
        cs.put(fieldToSet.get(cs.Status), true);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails); 
    update cases;
  } 
}
```

Which is nearly 60 lines shorter than your code. As a bonus, once you fix your unit test to use the correct Responsibility Center name, you should have 100% code coverage.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox thank you so much for the reply. I never used a map, now it is time to learn about it. I tried to test it, but I am getting the error with:
Map<String, Id> statusToTemplateName = new Map<String, Id>{
        'Ready for Email' => templateIds.get('Template1').Id,
        'Waiting for Customer' => templateIds.get('Template2').Id
Variable does not exist: Id (on both lines) 
I was trying to find some information, but as I wrote I've never use maps, and because of that I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: @ApexNewbie The .Id shouldn't be there, sorry. Let me fix that real quick.

Comment: @ApexNewbie For Map, see [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm). These are incredibly useful, you'll need them often, so you should definitely take the time to learn them.