# Exception: No body supplied for the file attachment.: [fileAttachments]

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, singleemailmessage, emailfileattachment

I have an Apex class that contains @future annotation method to send email. A Visualforce page is rendered as pdf and is sent as an email. I'm getting an exception in test class-

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, No body supplied for the file attachment.: [fileAttachments]

Controller code(@future annotated)-

```
    PageReference pdf =  Page.ReceiptPrintPage;                       
        pdf.getParameters().put('AccId',parameter1); 
        pdf.getParameters().put('year',String.valueOf(parameter2));
        pdf.setRedirect(true);
        // Take the PDF content            
        Blob b;
      try{
            b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        }catch(Exception ex){
          System.debug('ex'+ex);
      }    

        // Create the email attachment
        String filename = parameter3 + '_receipt_' + parameter2 + '.pdf'; 
      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        //Messaging.EmailFileAttachment.setContentType(param1)                
        efa.setFileName(filename);
        efa.setBody(b);                               

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        String subject = 'Recurring Donations Receipt for the Fiscal Year - ' + parameter2;                                                   
        body = 'Hello';
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {parameter4});
        email.setPlainTextBody(body);           
      email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});                                             
        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

Test code-

```
    PageReference pdf =  Page.ReceiptPrintPage;
    pdf.getParameters().put('AccId',a1.Id); 
    pdf.getParameters().put('year',String.valueOf(fiscalYear));
    pdf.setRedirect(true);                
    Blob b;
    try{
        System.debug('before test content');      
        //b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        b = pdf.getContent();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('ex'+ex);
    }  

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    String filename = 'Receipt_' + fiscalYear + '.pdf';                                  
    efa.setFileName(filename);
    efa.setBody(b);                                   

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String body = 'Testing Email';
    String subject = 'Recurring Donations Receipt for the Fiscal Year - ' + fiscalYear; 

    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'company@domain.com'});                
    email.setPlainTextBody(body);           
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});                                           
    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

How can I set body for file attachment?

Comment: Please phrase your questions as *questions*. That is to say, your question will be better formed (more on topic according to the [help]) if you *ask* something rather than suggest to others that they help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for providing solutions. I finally found the perfect solution to my stated problem. As suggested by Mohith Shrivastava [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97223/test-fails-because-of-testmethod-do-not-support-getcontent-call).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *correct*.
The issue you are having is that `pdf.getContent();` is throwing an exception and the Blob variable `b` is null by the time `efa.setBody(b);` is executed (because it was never initialised).

Edit with what I mean, including the suggestion of @Rahul Sharma/Bob ;)

If you put the logic outside, its easier to cover with a test, and then you just leave the send-message out. something like...

```
private /*or public*/ static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage getEmailMessage(String paramAccountId, String paramYear, String paramFilePrefix, String paramToAddress);
    PageReference pdf =  Page.ReceiptPrintPage;
    pdf.getParameters().put('AccId',paramAccountId);
    pdf.getParameters().put('year',paramYear);
    pdf.setRedirect(true);
    // Take the PDF content
    Blob b;
    try {
        if (Test.IsRunningTest()) {
            b = Blob.valueOf('My awesome pdf, but txt');
        } else {
            b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('ex'+ex);
        // actually do something about it, like sending an error message to an admin or opening a ticket or something
    }


    // Create the email attachment
    String filename = paramFilePrefix + '_receipt_' + paramYear + '.pdf';
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    //Messaging.EmailFileAttachment.setContentType(param1)
    efa.setFileName(filename);
    efa.setBody(b);

    // Sets the paramaters of the email
    String subject = 'Recurring Donations Receipt for the Fiscal Year - ' + paramYear;
    body = 'Hello';
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {paramToAddress});
    email.setPlainTextBody(body);
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    return email;
}
```

Having in the @future method something like

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {getEmailMessage(parameter1, String.valueOf(parameter2), parameter3, paramater4)});
```

and in the test method something like

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage toBeTested = getEmailMessage(parameter1, String.valueOf(parameter2), parameter3, paramater4);

System.assertEquals(new List<String>{parameter4}, toBeTested.getToAddresses());
System.assertNotEquals(null, toBeTested.getFileAttachments());
System.assertEquals('Recurring Donations Receipt for the Fiscal Year - ' + String.valueOf(parameter2), toBeTested.getSubject());
....
```

Comment: So how to initialize? Yes you are right that pdf.getContent(); is throwing exception. What is the workaround for that?

Comment: The code you pasted is part of your test method or part of your @future method?

Comment: It is part of test method. I'll edit the question and put @future method. Please check the update in a while.

Comment: in the test code you could replace `b = pdf.getContent();` by `b = Blob.valueOf('Testing 1 2 3')`. But if you really want to make a test, you should do a method that returns the email, and then in the test, make sure that the content of the email is what you expect and so on. Then in the method, use what @Rahul Sharma says, to generate the blob of 'Testing 1 2 3' only for test context, and then you could check for that in your asserts

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand that. "do a method that returns the email", means? In controller class you mean? Please elaborate in form of answer if possible.

Comment: Let's see if the idea is a bit more clear now. (Not perfect, but a bit better)

Comment: Hearty thanks for the explanation. I'll try this out and update you.