# Understanding the proper response for a mock callout

Tags: apex, callout, apextestrunresult

I have code that I am trying to test that includes a getcontent() request. I know I need to create a mock callout for this, however I don't know what the proper response should be. How can I find out what the proper response should be?

The VF Page calls the RedirectWithVariables controller (see code below). The controller then calls the StaticFunctions class (see code below). The StaticFunctions class currently has an "if (test.IsRunningTest) line that I want to remove and instead use mocking to replace "html = pReference.getContent().toString();  " with mocking. The problem is I don't know what a mock response to that call would look like. I can guess it would be something like

```
<label for="CF00NK0000000Yt1b"><span class="requiredMark">*</span>Name</label>
```

But I don't know what "CF00NK0000000Yt1b" represents or how to implement this. Can anyone help?

**RedirectWithVariables Controller**

```
/**
 *      @author Frank Neezen
 *      @date   15/11/2012
        @description    Class for the Redirect With Variables page. 
 
        Function: Handles the controller logic for the RedirectWithVariables page.
       
 */

public with sharing class RedirectWithVariablesController {


    /*
     *  Method name:    redirectUser
     *  @description    Redirects the user to the given object + parameters
     *  @return         PageReference The page the user needs to be redirect to.
     */
    public PageReference redirectUser(){
        
        //Get object name
        String strObject = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('object');
        
        //Allow record type selection? if set to yes, then allow RTS
        String strEnableRTS = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('allowRTS');
        
        //If there is an object name
        if(strObject != ''){
            
            //Create a generic object based on the name
            Schema.Sobjecttype oGenericObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strObject);     
            
            //If a real object has been given
            if(oGenericObj != null){
                
                PageReference pReference = null;
                
                //Check if we have to use record type selection or not
                if(strEnableRTS != '' && strEnableRTS == 'true'){
                    
                    //If we need RTS, the URL will have to point to the recordtypeselect.jsp
                    if(oGenericObj.getDescribe().custom){
                        pReference = new PageReference('/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=' +oGenericObj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()+ '&save_new_url=/' + oGenericObj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e?');                   
                    }
                    else{
                        pReference = new PageReference('/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=' + strObject + '&save_new_url=/' + oGenericObj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e?');                   
                    }
                        
                }else{
                
                    //Else create the page reference to the edit page of this object
                    pReference = new PageReference('/' +  oGenericObj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
                }
                
                system.debug('oGenericObj is ' +oGenericObj);

                //Also get a separate reference - we always need to get the parameters based on the edit page
                PageReference pEditReference = new PageReference('/' +  oGenericObj.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
                system.debug('pEditReference is '+pEditReference);
                //Get all current parameters - this could be either edit page or the record type selection.
                Map<String, String> m = pReference.getParameters();
                
                //Create the parameters for the URL (translates field to ID)             
                m.putAll(StaticFunctions.createLabelParameters(pEditReference, oGenericObj.newSObject()));
                m.put('nooverride', '1');
                m.put('retURL', ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL'));
                
                
                    
                //Return the page
                return pReference;
            }
        }
        
        //Return null if someone is playing with the URL
        return null;
    }
}
```

**StaticFunctions Class**

```
/**
 *      @author Frank Neezen
        @description    Class for static functions used during the project.
 
        Function: Repository of useful functions. 
 */

public with sharing class StaticFunctions {
    
    // Variables used in getLabel function to store object and it's fields metadata
    public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mSchema = new Map<String,Schema.SObjectType>();
    public static Schema.SObjectType oSchema = null;
    public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mFields = null;

    /*
     *  Method name:    createLabelParameters
     *  @description    Creates a set of parameters given an sobject. If the label is mentioned in the URL Get Parameter
     *                  and has a value, this label is translated to the ID and linked to the value
     *  @param          List<Medical_Event_vod__c> lEvents  List of medical events
     *  @return         void
     */
    public static Map<String, String> createLabelParameters(PageReference pReference, sObject oGeneric){ 
        
        system.debug('pReference is ' +pReference);
        
        //store the html from the page reference
        String html = '';

        //Dummy data for testing if we do tests                
        //if (test.isRunningTest()){
        //    html = '<label for="CF00NK0000000Yt1b"><span class="requiredMark">*</span>Name</label>';
        //}
        //else{
            
            //get the HTML contents
            html = pReference.getContent().toString();      
        //}
        
        // Capture the accountId of the case
        String def_account_id= System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('def_account_id');
        
        //Create the map that stores the label to label ID
        Map<String, String> mLabelToID = new Map<String, String>();
        
        //Create the regular expression to fetch all labels
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile('<label for="(.*?)">(<span class="requiredMark">\\*</span>)?(.*?)</label>').matcher(html);
        
        //While there are labels
        while (m.find()) {
            
            //Label is stored in the 4th column 
            String label = m.group(3);
            
            //Id is stored in the second column
            String id = m.group(1);
            
            //Add it to the map (split on _, on occasion we have a _top somewhere)
            mLabelToID.put(label, id.split('_')[0]);                  
        }
        
        // Create new parameter set
        Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>();
        
        //for each field in our object
        for (SObjectField field : oGeneric.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
            
            //Get the field description object
            DescribeFieldResult f = field.getDescribe();
            
            String label = f.getLabel();        //Get label name
            String apiName = f.getName();       //Get API name
            
            //Get the parameter from GET
            Object value = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(apiName);
                    
            //If we have a value
            if (value != null) {
                
                //If there is a label              
                if (mLabelToID.containsKey(label)) {

                    // Format the given value as required
                    String valueAsString;
                    if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Date) {
                        valueAsString = ((Date) value).format();
                    } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Datetime) {
                        valueAsString = ((Datetime) value).format();
                    } else if (f.getType() == DisplayType.Boolean) {
                        valueAsString = ((Boolean) value) ? '1' : '0';
                    } else {
                        valueAsString = String.valueOf(value);
                    }
                     
                    //If it is a lookup field, we expect to add the ID as well
                    if(f.getReferenceTo().size()>0){
                        
                        //We assume that the variable will contain ID_ for a lookup parameter
                        String strIDLookup = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID_' + apiName).trim();
                                                                                            
                        //If not null, add the parameter (use _lkid to reference the ID field)
                        if(strIDLookup!=null)
                             params.put(mLabelToID.get(label) + '_lkid', strIDLookup);
                    }
                    
                                                          
                    //Set the ID to the value
                    params.put(mLabelToID.get(label), valueAsString);
                  
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Check if we also have to set the Record Type
        String strRecordType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');
        
        //If we have a record type
        if(strRecordType != null){
            
            //Lets find the ID
            List<RecordType> lTypes = [ Select  Id
                                        From    RecordType
                                        Where   Name =: strRecordType
                                        And     SObjectType =: oGeneric.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() ];
            
            //If we can find the record type, add it as a parameter
            if(lTypes.size() > 0)
                 params.put('RecordType', lTypes[0].Id);
                        
        }
        
        //Populate the accountId if its alreday present
        if(def_account_id!=null)
            params.put('def_account_id',def_account_id);
        
        //Return the set of label ID's to values
        return params;
            
    }

    /*
     *  Method name:    getLabel
     *  @description    Gets the label name given an API 
     *  @param          String  The API name of object from which the field lable is required
     *  @return         String  The Label name for the given API Name of a Field
     */
    public static String getLabel(String objectName,String strFieldName){
        
        //Get global schema
        if(mSchema.size() == 0){
            mSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
            
            //Get field schema for medical event
            oSchema = mSchema.get(objectName);
            
            //Get mapping of fields 
            mFields = oSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();    
                
        }
        
        //check if it exists, else return null
        if(mFields.containsKey(strFieldName.toLowerCase()))     
            return mFields.get(strFieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();  //return field label
        
        return strFieldName;
    }
    
  
}
```

Comment: whats the problem with using if (test.isRunningTest()) -- i see for test purposes you have a test html on it ...you are running get content

get content returns a blob
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm

I just want to understand what purpose will having a mock serve for you...

Comment: So, a) the I have no idea what the label retrieved is (the code was written by someone else), b) I have been told numerous times on these boards that it isn't best practice, and c) I don't get coverage for any of the code under "//If there is a label" so I assumed that the label from the html string was not valid. I am going through the code to check.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with Object value = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(apiName); so either way wouldn't I need to create a mock?

Comment: So just to clarify, you aren't actually making any callouts in this code. As Arihant has shared, the getContent method returns the HTML content of a particular instance of a page. If you're wanting to test this logic without using the dummy HTML that has been commented out, you need to instantiate an instance of your VF page, and pass that page reference to the createLabelParameters method within your test.

Comment: Callum, I was looking at this answer which said it was considered a callout (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97223/test-fails-because-of-testmethod-do-not-support-getcontent-call) But if not, then how do I instantiate the VF Page in the test class but get the content of that page in the class without getting the error message that getContent() is not supported in Test Method?